# Exist attribute in Realm Db which like NotMapped?

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, realm

I change the db in my app, from sqlite EF to realmDB, I cant found any NotMapped equivalent attribure.

```
    Public string MainCoordY { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] private double Y => double.Parse(MainCoordY .Replace(".", ","));
```

Answer (score 2):

Realm will automatically ignore properties that don't have a setter, so your example above shouldn't need an explicit attribute. Additionally, properties that have non-automatic accessors will also be ignored. Finally, there's the [`[Ignored]`](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/dotnet/10.0.0/reference/Realms.IgnoredAttribute.html) attribute that tells Realm not to process a property and is roughly equivalent to `[NotMapped]`:

```
public class Person : RealmObject
{
    // Ignored because it doesn't have a setter
    public string ClassName => "Person";

    private string name;

    // Ignored because it's not an auto property
    public string Name
    {
        get => this.name;
        set => this.name = value ?? throw new Exception("Name must not be null");
    }

    // Ignored because of the attribute
    [Ignored]
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you say "non-automatic accessor" are you referring to when realm states in its documentation "Realm will not store a property with a custom setter"? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/dotnet/model-data/define-object-model/#custom-setters

Comment: Correct - properties that have custom implementation of a getter/setter will be ignored.